# Missing Right Peren, Oracle syntax error

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pdo

Trying to make this table, getting `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`.

Definition:

```
   CREATE TABLE "crawler" (
        "id" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE DEFAULT master_seq.NEXTVAL,
        "title" VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "url" VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "body" LONG NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "depth" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE DEFAULT '1',
        "updated" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "linked_from" VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "crawled" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE DEFAULT '0'
    );
```

Full text:

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 907 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00907:
>   missing right parenthesis
>   (/core-php-src-5.2.5/php-5.2.5/ext/pdo_oci/oci_statement.c:146)

(via PHP/PDO).

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you really using PHP5.2.5?

Comment: Using a long datatype has not been recommended by Oracle for years (even though the metadata still uses it).  Also why are you quoting the numbers 1 and 0 when they are set as defaults for a number column?

Comment: I'm trying to port a MySQL table to Oracle. The examples I Googled had the numbers quoted. Works in MySQL and removing them didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the Sequence in your create table statement until Oracle 11g.I assume you are using Oracle Version 11g and below.

In order to use an auto increment Id in your create table, you have to use a sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_table_sequence
START WITH 1
MAXVALUE 999999999999999
MINVALUE 1
NOCYCLE;
```

and a trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT my_table_sequence.NEXTVAL
   INTO   :new.id
   FROM   dual;
END;
```

and
either use a trigger like above 
or 
in your insert statements, invoke sequence.nextval for inserting data into the table.

Change your create table definition this way

```
 CREATE TABLE "crawler" (
    "id" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "title" VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "url" VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "body" LONG NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "depth" NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT '1' NOT NULL,
    "updated" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "linked_from" VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "crawled" NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL ENABLE 
);
```

Comment: @calbeload . . . Unfortunately, that doesn't fix the problem in SQL Fiddle.  I think there might be a back character in the definition.

Comment: Reverse the order like DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL ENABLE

Comment: very much appreciated.